# Subject Verb Object Pattern

Tags: subjects

Can someone tell me what are subject, verb, direct object and indirect object in the following sentence: "Show me that photo.".

Answer (score 1):

(You) [SUBJECT] show [VERB] me [INDIRECT OBJECT] that photo [DIRECT OBJECT]